Splitting a winforms form into multiple partials confuses the VS designer
I have a largeish Windows Forms form that has a tab control and quite a lot of functionality that all has to go in one class (otherwise it can't access the form's controls), so I'd like to split it up into partials.  However, I can't seem to find a way to do this without confusing the designer.  As a much simpler example, if I create a new winforms project with one form and break it into 2 partials (3 if you include the auto-generated Form1.Designer.cs):
Form1.cs
namespace PartialsApp;

public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show("Button 1 clicked");
    }
}

Form1_Button2.cs
namespace PartialsApp;

[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code")]
partial class Form1 {
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show("Button 2 clicked");
    }
}

Whilst the project builds and the form works correctly, the Form1.cs file loses the "form" icon in the solution explorer and double clicking it no longer opens the form designer, presumably because the [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code")] attribute is applying to all partial instances of the form, making it think that everything is code and nothing is design.  However, if I remove that attribute, the form icon appears next to Form1_Button2.cs and double-clicking that brings up a designer with an empty form and generates an erroneous resource file to go along with it.
Is there any way to split the form implementation up into partials without confusing the designer?

Have you tried calling the file Form1.Button2.cs ( dot instead of underscroe ) ?

I dislike the idea of splitting form. The big part of winforms designer rely on autogenerated code, therefore partial, not because it expect you to split it even further. The idea with attribute, which should only affect a part of class is even more weird. It just doesn't work this way. You may want to consider composition instead of inheritance, ideally separating business logic from view completely, but multiple small isolated UserControls is an intended way.

Splitting forms code into partials works just fine, but you need the correct naming convention. Given the primary file "MyForm.cs" you would use dotted names: "MyForm..cs", for example MyForm.Properties.cs

Also you should try removing the DesignerCategory("code") attribute.

@MatthewWatson Won't double clicking on this file open the designer?

@shingo Yeah, removing it probably won't help. Can probably ignore that suggestion. :)

@Fildor That seems to kind of work although the file still gets a 'form' icon next to it even though it's beneath Form1.cs hierarchically, and if I move event handler code into there, the designer won't open up that file when I try to edit that event, it still opens up the main file that no longer contains the event handler.

are u using .net or framework ? Winforms projects using .net have a different designer, I found it somewhat more stable but still has the same flaws

I'm using .net 9.

If you want to split a form class, any newly split class will default to having the Form subtype, causing it to open in the designer by default. Based on my research, in projects that do not use the Sdk for building, it is possible to achieve this through a custom Compile process. However, in .NET 9, which uses the Microsoft.NET.Sdk, many build processes are implicit, including how resource files are generated and how the compilation process works. This means that .NET 9 does not support splitting a form class into additional parts.
